# Why is the texture of my object not showing up?

Tags: java, 3d, blender, java-3d

Here is a chair i created using blender:

[image]

Now, when i display it using Java3D this is what i get:

[image]

Why is my texture not showing up in java? Here is my code for displaying the chair:

```
package com;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;

import javax.media.j3d.Alpha;
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.Background;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
import javax.media.j3d.RotationInterpolator;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.microcrowd.loader.java3d.max3ds.Loader3DS;
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.Scene;
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.objectfile.ObjectFile;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class LoadAnObject extends Applet
{
    public LoadAnObject()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(config);
        add("Center", canvas);

        BranchGroup content = getScene();
        content.compile();

        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(content);
    }

    public BranchGroup getScene()
    {
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

        Loader3DS loader = new Loader3DS();

        Scene scene = null;

        try
        {
            scene = loader.load("/Users/John/ArtOfIllusion/Chair.3ds");
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        TransformGroup rotateGroup = new TransformGroup();
        Transform3D rotate = new Transform3D();
        rotate.rotX(- Math.PI / 8);
        rotateGroup.setTransform(rotate);
        rotateGroup.addChild(scene.getSceneGroup());

        TransformGroup objSpin = new TransformGroup();
        objSpin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        //objSpin.addChild(new ColorCube(.5));
        Alpha rotationAlpha = new Alpha(-1, 4000);
        RotationInterpolator rotator = new RotationInterpolator(rotationAlpha, objSpin);

        BoundingSphere boundSphere = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 200);
        rotator.setSchedulingBounds(boundSphere);
        objSpin.addChild(rotator);
        objSpin.addChild(rotateGroup);

        TransformGroup moveGroup = new TransformGroup();
        Transform3D move = new Transform3D();
        move.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f));
        moveGroup.setTransform(move);
        moveGroup.addChild(objSpin);

        group.addChild(moveGroup);

        Background background = new Background(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        background.setApplicationBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        group.addChild(background);

        Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0), 100.0);
        Vector3f light1Direction = new Vector3f(0, 0, 10);
        DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight(light1Color, light1Direction);
        light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        group.addChild(light1);

        return group;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Frame frame = new MainFrame(new LoadAnObject(), 256, 256);
    }
}
```

The file format I'm using is .3ds, here is where i got the loader from:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/java3dsloader/

How do i get the texture of the chair to show up in java?

---

edit:

I compiled my chair into a .3ds file instead of an object file, i now have to use a .3ds loader which i got from here:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/java3dsloader/

The code doesn't change too much, instead of using an ObjectFile i now use a Loader3DS

[image]

So now obviously you can see that the material transferred over, but not the texture, how do i get the texture to show up?

Comment: +1 for elaborated question. I don't understand why someone has downvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java apparently doesn't load textures unless they are generated from an image. The only way I've been able to load textures is from an image mapped texture. I've tried a couple different formats and i still got nothing. If you are going to try to use textures in Java3D make sure you use Image Mapped textures!!